# How to send note attribute field in order data in Shopify liquid?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template, shopify-liquid

I had a use case in shopify theme (liquid) where I have the following

I have to store some data in local storage
I have to send the data in the note_attribute field of the order object (When user makes an order).

I have done 1. But I could not send the data in orders as customizing Checkout page is deprecated.
How can I achieve this ? Should I use the deprecated Checkout.liquid. Or is there some other way ?

Also, the main use case we are trying to solve is, we send affiliate data in note_attributes field of orders, then the orders webhook sends the affiliate data to our servers.
Is there another way to achieve this?